# Why direct substitution approach leads to incorrect answer in $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{e^{1/x}-1}{e^{1/x}+1}$?

Tags: limits

My attempt: substituted x=0 and got the indeterminate form $\frac\infty\infty$ and then used L'hospital rule and got the answer as 1.

But the correct answer is "the limit does not exist", as left hand limit=-1  and is not equal to right hand limit=1.

What exactly is wrong in the approach? Am i missing something?

i understand that the numerator and denominator in $$\frac{e^{1/x}-1}{e^{1/x}+1}$$ are both discontinuous at x=0 but while finding limit we dont care about the value of the function at x=0 but only in the NBD of x=0.

But generally when solving $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} (1+x)^\frac{1}{x}$$  , we say the limit has the indeterminate form $1^\infty$ and  then use algebra techniques to solve it. (despite the fact that  $(1+x)^\frac{1}{x}$ is not defined at x=0)

how do i know when i can apply direct substitution and use the standard algebra tricks for standard indeterminate forms like $\frac\infty\infty$, $1^\infty$ , $0^0$ and when do i know that applying direct substitution is not appropriate because the limit doesn't exist.

What would the typical approach be then to solve a limit question pertaining to general functions if assumed i do not know for certain that the numerator and denominator are continuous at a particular point? Also if possible please show me how your typical approach would be used to solve $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} (1+x)^\frac{1}{x}$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{e^{1/x}-1}{e^{1/x}+1}$ and still arrive at the correct answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The limit of the numerator (or denominator) is not $\infty$;  it does not exist, even in the infinite sense. LR does not apply.

Comment: The limit is not of the form $\infty/\infty$, so you can't apply L'Hopital's rule. The expression $1/x$ only approaches $\infty$ when $x$ approaches $0$ from above; when $x$ approaches $0$ from below, $1/x$ approaches $-\infty$, so $e^{1/x}$ approaches $0$.

Comment: @Joe but there is a (1/x) even in $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} (1+x)^\frac{1}{x}$ and we still say that it has the indeterminate form  $1^\infty$ and not $1^{-\infty}$ when x approaches zero from left.

Comment: @DavidMitraTo put it simply say if i were to find $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} (\csc(x))^x$ how would i proceed if i am not sure if the limit even exists and i am unable to equate right hand limit to left hand limit to ascertain that. The general solution given is its of the indeterminate form $\infty^0$ and then use the standard algebra tricks to solve. But here similar to $e^{\frac1x}$ $\csc(x)$ also behaves the same way but nevertheless we substitute zero and say it has one of the indeterminate forms.

Comment: @Nikhilonly: I personally would not say that the limit which you speak of is of the form $1^{\infty}$, since it is not the case that the exponent approaches $\infty$ when $x$ approaches $0$ from below. I think most mathematicians would agree with me.

Comment: To me, a "limit of the form $1^\infty$" means that you are dealing with $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)^{g(x)}$, where $f(x)\to 1$ and $g(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to a$. This type of limit is called an "indeterminate form" because its value depends on what the functions $f$ and $g$ are – just knowing that $f(x)\to 1$ and $g(x)\to\infty$ is not enough to *determine* the value of the limit. By contrast, if we know that $f(x)\to 2$ and $g(x)\to 3$, then it follows at once that $f(x)^{g(x)}\to6$. In particular, we do need not more information about what the functions $f$ and $g$ are to draw this conclusion.

Comment: Sorry, I should have written $f(x)^{g(x)}\to 8$ rather than $f(x)^{g(x)}\to6$ in my previous comment! Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

I always say that substituing $x_0$ in $f(x)$ when calculating the $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$ is an incorrect approach.

In this case, namely, $\frac{1}{x}\to \pm\infty$ when $x\to 0^{\pm}$. So, $e^{\frac{1}{x}}\to +\infty$ when $x\to 0^+$ and $e^{\frac{1}{x}}\to 0$ when $x\to 0^-$. Thus:
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{e^{1/x}-1}{e^{1/x}+1}=1$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{e^{1/x}-1}{e^{1/x}+1}=-1$$
And the limit does not exists.

Again, when you substitute $x=0$ you lost the case $x\to 0^-$ and wrongly conclude that $e^{\frac{1}{x}}\to +\infty$ when $x\to 0$.

Comment: That is my confusion as well, in this case the direct substitution neglects the fact that $e^{\frac{1}{x}}\to 0$ when $x\to 0^-$ but in $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} (1+x)^\frac{1}{x}$ the power has the same behaviour, but we dont disregard it and conclude it has the indeterminate form $1^\infty$ and not $1^{-\infty}$.

Comment: Also if say i want to find $\lim_{x\to a}F(x)$ would you say i have to check if $\lim_{x\to a^+}F(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a^-}F(x)$ converge to the same indeterminate form and then apply whatever standard algebra tricks i would apply for that particular indeterminate form?

Comment: To put it simply say if i were to find $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} (\csc(x))^x$ how would i proceed if i am not sure if the limit even exists and i am unable to equate right hand limit to left hand limit to ascertain that. The general solution given is its of the indeterminate form $\infty^0$ and then use the standard algebra tricks to solve. But here similar to $e^{\frac1x}$ $\csc(x)$ also behaves the same way but nevertheless we substitute zero and say it has one of the indeterminate forms.